# My Visual Studio 2015 cannot find essential dependencies for building a project

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Before, I used Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10, It works fine.

Now, I want to use `CFormView` class in MFC (not in Visual Studio 2017), so I installed the Visual Studio 2015 (now with 2 Visual Studio in my system), but Visual Studio 2015 cannot even compile a simple project (the codes like blew in a "empty console application"):
[image]

The error messages when building the solution:

`TRACKER : Error TRK005: Cannot find: "cl.exe".`
[image]

The first of the 408 errors show:

`cannot open source file "vcruntime.h"`
[image]

So I found this file in `Computer Disk C`:
[image]

I am confused! When I installed Visual Studio 2015, I select the `Computer Disk D`:
[image]
Why some important Visual Studio 2015 files is in another disk `Disk C` with no Visual Studio 2015 program file `Disk D`?

Then I check the Properties of my Visual Studio project, there is no `Disk C` header files address in the default include dictionary:

`$(VC_IncludePath)`
`$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)`
[image]

[image]

I am a beginner, and would you please tell me why this happened, and how to fix my Visual Studio 2015 to make it work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you install the C/C++ compiler?

Comment: @Nina I think so, the compiler should installed when I installed the Visual Studio.

Comment: While it is commendable that you've got the screenshots it is also **essential** that you add a **verbatim text copy** of the compiler warnings so that future readers can find the question with google

Comment: @Jay The compiler doesn't automatically get installed. During the visual studio installation screen you pick which assets of Visual Studio you'd like to install.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for reminding me, I have edited my question.

Comment: @Nina  I understand what you mean, when installed Visual Studio, I selected the C/C++ components.

Comment: @Jay Can you open the command prompt and type `cl` and see if the command is recognised?